# Spark Java Application no cores and waiting

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to spark and I'm trying to develop my first application. I'm only trying to count lines in a file but I got the error:

```
2015-11-28 10:21:34 WARN  TaskSchedulerImpl:71 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I have enough cores and enough memory. I read that can be a firewall problem but I'm getting this error both on my server and on my macbook and for sure on the macbook there is no firewall. If I open the UI it says that the application is WAITING and apparently the application is getting no cores at all:

```
         Application ID          Name   Cores   Memory per Node      State  
app-20151128102116-0002 (kill)  New app   0       1024.0 MB         WAITING
```

My code is very simple:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(new String("New app"));
sparkConf.setMaster("spark://MacBook-Air.local:7077");
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("/Users/mattiazeni/Desktop/test.csv.bz2");

if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
    logger.info(textFile.count());
}
```

if I try to run the same program from the shell in scala it works great.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about using Scala? It's a great language. Do you have enough RAM over?

Comment: This code will be embedded in the main application which is in Java so I cannot use Scala. About the RAM, I have enough for sure on the server, 16GB and 8GB on the macbook.

Comment: What's the corresponding Scala code? Also, you can combine Java and Scala code with sbt (or maven) just fine.

Comment: Are you running in standalone mode? And if you use spark-submit can you please provide the spark-submit command.

Answer (score 0):

Check that workers are running - there should be at least one worker listed on the Spark UI at http://:8080
If not are running, use /sbin/start-slaves.sh (or start-all.sh)